# pymysql.connect raises "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given"

Tags: python, pymysql

This is the Python code where I am establishing a database connection. But I am getting a type error in my code. What is the issue?

```
import pymysql

connnection = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname")
```

Error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Full Code/COllectUrls.py", line 21, in <module>
   connnection = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Comment: Add the full stack of the error please.

Comment: It is a known bug in `pymysql`. Try this `pymysql.connect(host=dbhost,user=dbuser,password=dbpass,database=dbname)`

Comment: It is always best to follow [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) which shows to sue named arguments...

Answer (score 16):

This solves the problem.

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             database='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Comment: Why does it solve the problem? What *was* the problem?

Answer (score 6):

This will work for 3.x versions.

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='db_emp', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print ("Database version : %s " % data)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: 3.x versions of what?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pymysql

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='12345678',database='studentdb')
```