# My python code refuses to connect to my MySQL database file

Tags: python, mysql

Please house I need help to connect my python code to my MySQL databse file. I am using a Windows 10 laptop. Please see my code below.

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword', 'sale')
```

Just with the code above, it releases an error message that says:

TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already answered.
This link might help you [TypeError: _init_() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66300530/typeerror-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-5-were-given)

Also always go through official documentation
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html